# How to change rethinkdb host port

Tags: rethinkdb

Hello i am trying to set a different port for rethinkdb host and it just won't work.(The default one is already used).

I have tried :

```
rethinkdb --bind all
rethinkdb --bind-http 9000
rethinkdb --bind {all|9000}
```

Comment: `--bind` stands for a hostname, not a port. Did you check `--driver-port ` as it's said in the [documentation](https://rethinkdb.com/docs/cli-options/)?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it using the `--http-port {portnr}` command